# IF ELSE in display column tag in struts2

Tags: if-statement, struts2

Hi i am using display column tag in struts2.
And want to format row on basis of data...

For example column hs boolean value.
If value is true i want display row in red font.
else in black font.

So how can i implement if else condition in display column tag in struts2?

I have check on net, bt solutions given ar
Can anyone give me code example for the same???

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't repeat the same and wrong questions !

Comment: I don't use the "display column tag" but with ordinary html adding a css class to a tag is to same as adding a string... <td class="<s:property value="myVar==false?'normal':'warning'"/>">table_data</td>, in other words OGNL supports the ternary operator just fine.

Comment: Oh course you can use such an expression in the cssClass attribute of a struts2 tag as well...

Answer (score 2):

Please check this and [link for Example](http://www.aoiblog.com/struts2-if-else-and-elseif-condition/)

```
 <s:if test="%{column ==true}">
 // do stuff to change row color
 </s:if>
 <s:else>
 // do stuff to change black font 
 </s:else>
```

Comment: this `column ==true` is grim. Never test a `boolean` against a `boolean`. It should obviously be `<s:if test="column">`